# cant reach content in block--views

Tags: views, theming

I am new to Drupal8.
How can i get the content ?
I call a view in page.html.twig like:

> {{ page.content.views_block__serviceboxen_block_1 }}

and created a template with name:

> block--views-block--serviceboxen-block-1.html.twig

How can i access to the content from my view in this template ?
I have no idea when i use

```
{% for row in rows %}
```

and

```
{% for item in items %}
```

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

solution: you can access the fields with 'content'

e.g. content.body or content.your_field_name.value

in a iteration it looks like:

```
<ul>
  {% for item in content['#view'].result %}
      {% set topic = item._entity %} {# just for shorter writing #}

       <li>{{ topic.title.value }}</li> {# or topic.yourFieldName.value #}

  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Hope it'll help